# Show text when you press a button

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to know a way to make some text appear when you press a button.
I've already created a button and a text box:

```
<Button Height="25" Width="200" Click="Button_Click" Content="Press this button"/>
<TextBlock Height="50" Width="300" Margin="243,147,249,222" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
```

Also, I've created a boolean for when you press the button, I don´t know if this is necessary or not.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Boolean button = true;
}
```

Comment: every control in WPF has a "Visibility" property

Comment: Add a `x:Name="txtSomething"` to `TextBlock` and then in the button click event add `txtSomething.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` that will just toggle that block, you don't have any text in it though.

Comment: In WPF a common pattern is a viewmodel that is used as the DataContext of your view. The DataContext enables databinding. You could use Visibilty of the TextBlock or assign the Text (both preferably using databinding and a viewmodel). Your boolean then becomes a property of a viewmodel and the BooleanToVisiblityConverter is used in the binding to change the Visiblity of the TextBlock.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, like MaxB said, every control in WPF has a "Visibility" property, that you can change between `Visible`, `Collapsed` or `Hidden`.

Since you already have a Handle for the `Button_Click` event, all you need to do now is give a name to your `TextBlock` with the `x:Name` property like-so :
`<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"/>`

Then, in the code of your handler, you can choose which `Visibility` to apply to the TextBlock according to the state of your boolean.
You can access the TextBlock properties by the name you gave it in the XAML file, like-so :
`this.MyTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a textbox you created a textblock. Firstly create a textbox and give it a name. Then on your Button_click method you can write `NameOfTextBox.Text = "Your text";`